# codigo no funciona fuera del IDE

Tags: sql

tengo una aplicacion JAVA sin entorno grafico que escribe en una base de datos en SQL, esta aplicacion dentro del IDE de NETBEANS funciona perfectamente, pero fuera del IDE, cuando intento ejecutar el .jar me muestra un error y me dice que no puede abrir la conexion de base de datos.

El codigo main principal es:

```
public class AutoPin {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while(true){
            Model claseModel = new Model();

            String myIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            System.out.println("myIP: " + myIP);

            claseModel.actualizarFechaUltimoPin(myIP);

            Thread.sleep(30*1000);
            System.out.println("Estado Actualizado.");
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo una clase auxiliar así:

```
public class Model{

    PreparedStatement s;
    protected Connection cn;

    String driverDataBase = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String DatoFinales = "jdbc:sqlserver:"
                + "//192.168.1.24\\pruebas"
                + ";applicationName="
                + "ProyectoPin"
                + ";databaseName="
                + "Prueba01"
                + ";user="
                + "wil"
                + ";password="
                + "1234";


    public Model() {

    }

    public void actualizarFechaUltimoPin(String ip) throws Exception{
        String comandoEjecutarSQL = "update PcTDT set FechaUltimoPin = GETDATE() "
                + "where IpPc = '"
                + ip
                + "'";

        //System.out.println("comandoEjecutarSQL: " + comandoEjecutarSQL);

        InsertarDatos(comandoEjecutarSQL);
    }   


    private boolean AbrirConexionBaseDatos() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverDataBase); //inicializo el driver             
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatoFinales, new Properties()); 
            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("no se pudo abrir la conexion con la DB");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void CerrarConexionBaseDatos() throws SQLException {
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("no se pudo cerrar la conexion con la DB");
        }
    }

    public String InsertarDatos(String comandos) throws Exception {
        String mensajeRetorno = "0";

        if( AbrirConexionBaseDatos() ){
            try {
                s = cn.prepareStatement(comandos, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                int i = s.executeUpdate(); //ejecuto los comandos guardados

                Integer risultato = -1;
                ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    risultato = rs.getInt(1);
                    if (risultato == 0) {
                        risultato = 1;
                    }
                }

                if (i > 0) {
                    //System.out.println("dato insertado o actualizado");
                    mensajeRetorno = "" + risultato;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("problema en el insertado o actualizado");
                }
                CerrarConexionBaseDatos();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.err.println(e1);
            }
        }

        return mensajeRetorno;
    }
}
```

y finalmente uso la libreria de sql sqljdbc4.jar, que cuando doy "`Clean and Bulit`" copia este archivo en una carpeta `Lib` junto al `.jar`.

Cuando ejecuto este `.jar` desde el IDE funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo ejecuto con `java -jar AutoPin.jar` me arroja el error de consola indicandome que `no se pudo abrir la conexion con la DB` que es un mensaje de la `clase Model` con lo cual verifico que si entra en esta clase, pero no resuelve la apertura de DB.

el Error que arroja por consola es:

> jun 29, 2018 2:34:10 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel
>   enableSSL INFORMACIËN: java.security path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\security Security providers: [SUN version
>   1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1 .8, XMLDSig
>   version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8, SunMSCAPI version 1.8] SSLContext
>   provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust facto
>   ries, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2) SSLContext provider services:
>   [SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory aliases:
>   [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1] , SunJSSE:
>   KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator aliases:
>   [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5,
>   1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1 .3.14.3.2.29] , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> sun.security.ssl.RSASignature ,
>   SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 ->
>   sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$S unX509 , SunJSSE:
>   KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImp
>   l$X509 aliases: [PKIX] , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 ->
>   sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryIm pl$SimpleFactory , SunJSSE:
>   TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$
>   PKIXFactory aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509] , SunJSSE:
>   SSLContext.TLSv1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context
>   aliases: [SSLv3] , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.1 ->
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS11Context , SunJSSE:
>   SSLContext.TLSv1.2 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS12Context ,
>   SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
>   aliases: [SSL] , SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default ->
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLConte xt , SunJSSE:
>   KeyStore.PKCS12 -> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore ] java.ext.dirs:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\li
>   b\ext

me podrian ayudar porfa?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: y si sacas el error personalizado y te fijas que error tira realmente el programa? mas alla de eso, pareceria que no esta encontrando la clase que buscas...

Comment: Posible duplicado de [un jar funciona en el entorno Netbeans, pero el jar no funciona fuera del entorno, que podria hacer para que funcione?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177536/un-jar-funciona-en-el-entorno-netbeans-pero-el-jar-no-funciona-fuera-del-entorn)

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques las preguntas. Edita la pregunta original

Comment: Gracias, he eliminado la pregunta repetida y traje el error a esta modulo tal como me lo sugeriste, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Parece un problema de certificados. Puede que si funciona en NetBeans hayas provisto de alguna forma los certificados en el mismo IDE, pero no hayas configurado el proyecto para que exporte los certificados con el `.jar`... Son sólo conjeturas, pero sería la explicación más lógica.

Comment: Una posible solución sería configurar el proyecto para que te cree el `.jar` incluyendo las librerías/dependencias.

Comment: Quiero intentar esto de exportar las configuraciones, pues el IDE ya me crea una carpeta de librerias donde esta el controlador de SQL que os menciono, pero quizas haya alguna configuracion que no haya hecho.... que configuracion recomendada debo considerar segun lo que me dices?